# Source code to string in variable

Tags: macos, applescript

In AppleScript Editor i can see that source_code has script content but row 2 fails for some reason.

```
set source_code to load script (POSIX file "/path/to/script.scpt")
word 2 of source_code
```

This don't work. I try to read AppleScript files to variable.

I don't try to run this loaded code but i need to get it as string.

---

It seems to fail because source_code is «script» not string. How this can be fixed? Thanks

```
set source_code to load script (POSIX file "/path/to/script.scpt")
word 2 of (source_code as string) -->error "Can’t make «script» into type string." number -1700 from «script» to string
word 2 of source_code -->error "Can’t get word 2." number -1728 from word 2
```

Comment: So the first line works (`set source_code ...`) but the second doesn't? What do you expect the second line to do exactly?

Comment: I expect to see second word in source code. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The `load script` command loads a script as an object to be run, rather than as text to read or manipulate.

If you want to access the actual text of your script, you can use osadecompile:

```
do shell script "osadecompile ~/Library/Scripts/test.scpt"
word 2 of result
```

Compiled scripts saved with AppleScript Editor usually have LF line endings in strings but CR line endings in other places. osadecompile converts all line endings to LF. `do shell script` converts line endings to CR unless you add a `without altering line endings` specifier.

Comment: Cool, this works! Thanks Lauri Ranta. Is there any way to get text which is in Description in bottom of AppleScript Editor window?

Comment: You could ask another question about it. The description is stored in the resource fork (`cat Untitled.scpt/..namedfork/rsrc` / `xattr -p com.apple.ResourceFork Untitled.scpt | xxd -r -p`) and it is actually rich text, but I don't know how to convert it to rtf or plain text.